# some wrongs when i start the server using service httpd restart

Tags: django, apache

when i ran `service httpd restart` i got the response shown that

```
AH00526: Syntax error on line 12 of /alidata/server/httpd/conf/vhosts/yigu.conf:
Invalid command 'WSGIScriptAlias', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

I guessed that might be the yigu.conf's problem, here's my yigu.conf file in `/alidata/server/httpd/conf/vhosts`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.xxx.com
    ServerAlias localhost
    ServerAdmin 123@123.com

    Alias /static/ /root/dict/static/

    <Directory /root/dict/static>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    WSGIScriptAlias /  /root/dict/dict/wsgi.py
    WSGIPythonPath /root/dict/

    <Directory /root/dict/dict>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I just follow the Django's document and wrote down that code. 
Then i ran `yum install libapache2-mod-wsgi`
And the result was

```
Loaded plugins: langpacks
No package libapache2-mod-wsgi available.
```

Then i tried `sudo apt-get libapache2-mod-wsgi` The result was `sudo: apt-get: command not found`

I was scared..everything was out of my control..Anyone could give me a hand ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably you are on CentOS, the package is just called `mod_wsgi`:

```
yum install mod_wsgi
```